# modifying/ getting rid of characters in text from txt file ussing vb.net

Tags: vb.net, text-files

I have a string of text i captured within AutoCAD `(0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000)` wich is saved to a text based file named position.txt.

as you probably have gatherd with a file name such as position.txt the text could be composed of any random number combination eg: (5.745379, 0.846290, 150.6459046).

However for it to be of any use to me I need the captured string to exist without spaces or brackets how can i achiev this in VB.net?

Comment: Wouldn't an AutoLISP solution be more useful?

Comment: You want to transform  "(5.745379, 0.846290, 150.6459046)" into  "5.7453790.846290150.6459046" ?

Comment: almost i want to keep the commas but the code below is adequate enougth to work rom thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx). Its probably not the most efficient way but it will get the job done.

```
Dim file as String = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("position.txt")

Dim output as String = file.Replace(" ", "") _
                           .Replace("(", "") _
                           .Replace(")", "")

My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("output.txt", output, false)
```

Comment: @albert - if you found my solution useful, please accept is as the 'accepted solution'. That will improve your reputation and so you'll be more likely to get answers in the future. Thanks:)

Comment: Qua the string replace I'd rather this to a variable then an output.txt file is that also compatable?

Comment: @albert - yes. The `Replace` function return a string variable. So in my code example, the `output` variable contains the contents of position.txt but without the spaces or parenthesis. Ignore the `WriteAllText` line

Answer (score 0):

as above

```
s = "(5.745379, 0.846290, 150.6459046)"
s = s.replace("(","")
s = s.replace(")","")
```

and then

```
dim answer() as string = s.split(",")
dim number as double
For each a as string in answer
  if double.tryparse(a,n) then
    console.writeline(n.tostring & " is a number")
  else
    console.writeline(n.tostring & " is rubbish")
next
```